# Не хочет запускаться Java код, 9 ошибок

Tags: java

Код:
package ru.leymooo.botfilter.captcha;

```
    import ru.leymooo.botfilter.captcha.generator.CaptchaPainter;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;



    public class CaptchaGen{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            private Font[] fonts = new Font[]
            {
                new Font( Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 128 / 2 ),
                new Font( Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 128 / 2 ),
                new Font( Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 128 / 2 )
            };

            private CaptchaPainter painter = new CaptchaPainter();

            for (int i = 100; i <= 105; i++)
            {
                public String xet = String.valueOf(i);
                public String namepng = xet + ".png";
                BufferedImage image = painter.draw( fonts[rnd.nextInt( fonts.length )],
                        MapPalette.colors[rnd.nextInt( MapPalette.colors.length )], String.valueOf( answer ) );
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File (namepng));
            }
    }
    }
```

Лог ошибок: leymooo\botfilter\captcha\CaptchaGeneration.java:11: error: illegal start of expression
private Font[] fonts = new Font[]
^

leymooo\botfilter\captcha\CaptchaGeneration.java:20: error: illegal start of type
for (int i = 100; i <= 105; i++)
^

leymooo\botfilter\captcha\CaptchaGeneration.java:20: error:  expected
for (int i = 100; i <= 105; i++)
^

leymooo\botfilter\captcha\CaptchaGeneration.java:20: error:  expected
for (int i = 100; i <= 105; i++)
^

leymooo\botfilter\captcha\CaptchaGeneration.java:22: error: illegal start of expression
public String xet = String.valueOf(i);
^

leymooo\botfilter\captcha\CaptchaGeneration.java:26: error:  expected
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File (namepng));
^

leymooo\botfilter\captcha\CaptchaGeneration.java:26: error:  expected
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File (namepng));
^

leymooo\botfilter\captcha\CaptchaGeneration.java:26: error: illegal start of type
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File (namepng));
^

leymooo\botfilter\captcha\CaptchaGeneration.java:28: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^

9 errors
error: compilation failed

Comment: Для начала исправьте сигнатуру метода `public static void makeCap()`

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь запустить цикл вне какого-либо метода. Создайте метод, поместите код в него и вызовите этот метод в `main`.

Comment: А можно поподробнее, я просто не шарю. Если не сложно пример кода

Comment: Я думаю вам это стОит посмотреть в любой книге для начинающих

Comment: Я изменил код, теперь ошибок стало 6

Comment: Нельзя менять текст вопроса с одного на другой. Если у вас возникли другие проблемы с уже исправленным кодом - стОит задать новый вопрос. А текущий откатить к изначальному, т.к. ответ был уже дан и он верный

Comment: @Xenon но как минимум скажу, что у метода вы забыли написать возвращаемый тип. Если конкретнее, то `void`

Comment: Теперь ошибок 5. Я изменил потому-что, мне надо будет опять ждать 40 минут

Comment: @Xenon таковы правила ресурса. Задаётся вопрос - даётся ответ. Нельзя его менять на другой или дополнительный. Иначе будет несоответствие вопроса и ответа. Увы. но таковы правила